# How do I make the arrows on qtrees and imported images compatible with the same compiler?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, arrows, dvips, qtree

The problem is that the images I have imported in the document will not compile ('no bounding box' error message comes out next to the image command) when I make the arrows on `qtree` by using `[tree-dvips]` visible in the document.

In order for the arrows to be visible in the document, I have to switch from the pdfLaTeX compiler to the LaTeX compiler (I am using ShareLaTeX). And LaTeX compiler seems incompatible with the `graphicx` package.

How do I solve this incompatibility such that both images and arrows show up?

Here are the minimum commands I used:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[!hbtp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{CorpusData.png}
    \caption{Corpus data (Diesing\&Zec 2011)}
    \label{fig:SerbianCorpusData}
    \end{figure}

    \ex.
    \qtreecenterfalse
    \Tree[.BeP \phantom{DP} [.Be' [.Be [.A$_i$ \node{trace}{ important} ] be ]     
    [.SC \qroof{this task}.DP 
    [.AP [.DegP very ] \node {adjective}{t$_i$} ] ] ] !\qsetw{3cm} ]
    \anodecurve [bl]{adjective}[b]{trace}{0.5in}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Three possible solutions: (i) don't use `tree-dvips` and switch to `tikz-qtree` or `forest` to draw trees. (Plenty of examples on the site, including how to draw arrow annotations.) (ii) convert your included images to `.eps` format (iii) switch to using xelatex to compile (might not work).  I would strongly recommend (i).

Answer (score 2):

It's really time for that `tree-dvips` example to be retired and replaced with something less obsolete (mea culpa). Qtree works great with pdflatex, and it plays well with tikz-- so here's how to draw arrows with `tikz`, without switching tree packages or (la)tex engines.

Just like with `tree-dvips`, you define positions on the page ("nodes") and draw the arrows after the tree is done, but while you are still on the same page. It works via auxfiles so you need to run latex a couple of times. Here's a complete working example; it works with pdflatex, so it is compatible with including png images.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{graphicx}
% tikz package, ``remember'' option, and two convenience commands
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture] 
% For drawing movement lines: \tnode{label}{target}
\def\tnode#1#2{{\tikz\node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=2pt](#1){#2};}}
% Use the target word as a label too
\def\xnode#1{\tnode{#1}{#1}}

\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{CorpusData.png}

\begin{enumerate}
\item[(1)] \Tree[.BeP ~ [.Be\1 
        [.Be [.A_i \xnode{important} ] be ]     
            [.SC \qroof{this task}.DP 
            [.AP [.DegP very ] \tnode{trace}{t_i} ] ] 
    ]  !\qsetw{3cm} ]

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->,thick](trace) edge [out=-90, in=-110](important); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace*{0.5cm}  % Reserve space under the tree for the arrow,
                 % which is invisible to TeX's boxing machinery
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here's the tree part of the output:

[image: tree with arrow]

The example includes tikz, turns on the `[remember picture]` feature, and defines two convenience macros: `\tnode` works just like the `\node` function of `tree-dvips`. `\xnode` uses the same word both for display and to label the position. (Only use `\xnode` if the target consists of letters only.)

```
% For drawing movement lines: \tnode{label}{target}
\def\tnode#1#2{{\tikz\node[shape=rectangle, inner sep=2pt](#1){#2};}}
% Use the target word as a label too
\def\xnode#1{\tnode{#1}{#1}}
```

The `tikzpicture[overlay]` block draws the arrow. `in` and `out` are angles giving the orientation of the arrows at the target and origin nodes (0 degrees = to the right). This overlay draws from the position labeled `trace` to the position labeled `important`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->,thick](trace) edge [out=-90, in=-110](important); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You can also add `[dashed]` to the path options to get a dashed arrow:

```
\path[->,thick,dashed](node1) edge [out=-160, in=-90] (node2);
```

This should be enough for the simple cases. The tikz enthusiasts on this site will help you if you need anything more complicated.

Comment: Is this possible to get the same arrow head in `tree-dvips` as like as `tikz-qtree`? pl advise...

Comment: @MadyYuvi, you specifically want to use `tree-dvips`? Any particular reason?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in that particular file, there are almost 50+ diagrams are drawn by using `tree-dvips`, if should change these to `tikz-qtree` will take huge time for me, and I don't have that much time.. Please suggest the best way...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but if you are just looking for a tree-dvips arrow example, use these parts from the original question: `\node{trace}{ important}`,  `\node {adjective}{t$_i$}`, `\anodecurve [bl]{adjective}[b]{trace}{0.5in}`. And/or read the tree-dvips documentation for more. If this doesn't do it, I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I didn't provide the exact requirement to you, please refer the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599218/is-this-possible-to-change-the-arrow-heads-like-as-tikz-qtree-currently-using