# Is this possible to change the arrow heads like as tikz-qtree? Currently using (qtree, tree-dvips)

Tags: arrows

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{qtree,tree-dvips}%commented purposely
\usepackage{linguex}

\begin{document}

\ex.\label{crossnestschema} \textit{Crossing and nested dependencies}
\a.\label{crossschema} {\node{5} X$_{\textrm{j}}$}  \ldots {\node{7}Y$_{\textrm{i}}$} \ldots {\node{5.5} X$_{\textrm{h}}$} \ldots  {\node{8}{\raisebox{-1pt}{\underline{\hspace{.5cm}}}}$_{\kern1.5pt\textrm{j}}$} \ldots {\node{6}{\underline{\hspace{.5cm}}}$_{\kern1.5pt\textrm{i}}$} \ldots {\node{8.5}{\underline{\hspace{.5cm}}}$_{\kern1.5pt\textrm{h}}$}
\anodecurve[br]{6}[b]{7}{.3in}
\anodecurve[br]{8}[b]{5}{.25in}
\anodecurve[br]{8.5}[b]{5.5}{.25in}


\end{document}
```

It works fine, and the output is:

[image]

I need a small change in this, I need the `arrow heads` should be as like as `tikz` arrow heads, e.g.,

[image]

I aware that it is possible if we go with `tikz-qtree`, but the problem is there are more occurrences are there in the entire file, so changing all items will require huge time, so please suggest how to get the `arrow heads` without changing `tree-dvips.sty`

Thanks a lot...